# What is going wrong inside of my loop?

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops

I've been trying to program the [Josephus problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem) and for some reason it is only working in some situations, I'm unsure why. The TL;DR of how it works is this:

You have X group of people in a circle. Every Nth person is going to be killed until only one final person remains. So say for example you have 10[AKA: X] people and you decide to kill every 3rd [AKA: Nth] person it will look like this:

1st round: 1, 2, (3 dies), 4, 5, (6 dies), 7, 8, (9 dies), 10

2nd round: 1, (2 dies because it is a continuous circle), 3, 5, (7 dies), 8, 10

3rd round: (1), 4, 5, (8), 10

4th round: 4, (5), 10

5th round: 4, (10)

And we are finally left with person #4 as the lone survivor.

My program does this perfectly fine. However, when I enter X as `55` and N as `17` I get the incorrect answer of person `27` when it should be person `40`. Can anyone tell me where my loop messes up?

Source code:

```
def solveJosephus(specifics):
    people = [int(x) for x in range(1,int(specifics[0])+1)]
    killPosition = int(specifics[1])
    positionCounter = 0
    sorted = False

    while not sorted:
        if len(people) == 1:
            print(people[0]) # Pyschologically scarred Winner!
            sorted = True
        for person in people:
            positionCounter += 1
            if positionCounter == killPosition:
                print(person)
                people.remove(person)
                positionCounter = 1

solveJosephus(raw_input().split())
```

Comment: It should be `people = range(1, int(specifics[0])+1)`. The built-in `range` function in Python 2.x is guaranteed to produce a list of ints, so mapping them to ints again is redundant.

Comment: Also, I believe a better time-complexity can be reached by iterating over a copy of an OrderedSet and removing elements from it: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576694/ Or perhaps just use the built-in Python set and iterate through a sorted list generated from the set, e.g. `for person in sorted(survivors):` It's also possible a recurrence relation can be found here which yields an efficient dynamic programming solution. The most efficient solution of all probably uses a math formula :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to all the [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29932868/3161440) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29932878/3161440) (telling you to make a copy of the list when iterating), another problem with your code is that you reset the `positionCounter` to 1 in this line: `positionCounter = 1`. It should be reset to 0. Here is the complete working code (works so far):

```
def solveJosephus(specifics):
    people = [int(x) for x in range(1,int(specifics[0])+1)]
    killPosition = int(specifics[1])
    positionCounter = 0
    sorted = False

    while not sorted:
        if len(people) == 1:
            print(people[0]) # Pyschologically scarred Winner!
            sorted = True
        for person in people[:]: #Make copy of iterating list
            positionCounter += 1
            if positionCounter == killPosition:
                print(person)
                people.remove(person)
                positionCounter = 0 #Important! 0 != 1

solveJosephus(raw_input().split())
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is you are removing people from the list while iterating through it.

What happens is the following:

Say you have `X = 5` and `N = 2`. Your list is `[1,2,3,4,5]`. You get to `index = 1` and person 2 dies. Now your list is `[1,3,4,5]`. The problem is your index still equals `1` but now that points to person 3. When you go two more places (index = 3), instead of killing person 4, you kill person 5.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you sometimes get the right or wrong answer, but I've always run into strange problems if I try to modify a list while iterating over it as your

```
for person in people:
    ...
    people.remove(person)
```

does.  Perhaps you can iterate over people.copy() instead so you aren't modifying the same list you're iterating over.